# Dynamic CSS issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

The below works fine in the LWC playground, but drop it in to the local preview or an org and the css does not behave.

I've discovered that the hover works on a single selector, but with sub selectors it simply doesnt behave correctly.

Here is a playground link (whilst active): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/b4msWR4hS/

I've noticed that this works fine on Safari, but not on Chrome.  I'm using a Mac with Chrome version Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

```
<template>
    <div class="stars" data-stars="1">
      <svg height="25" width="23" class="star" data-rating="1">
        <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>
      </svg>
      <svg height="25" width="23" class="star" data-rating="2">
        <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>
      </svg>
      <svg height="25" width="23" class="star" data-rating="3">
        <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>

      </svg>
      <svg height="25" width="23" class="star" data-rating="4">
        <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>
      </svg>
      <svg height="25" width="23" class="star" data-rating="5">
        <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>
      </svg>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
.stars {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
.stars:hover .star polygon {
  fill: #ffd055 !important;
}
.stars .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars .star:hover ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8 !important;
}
.stars[data-stars] .star polygon {
  fill: #ffd055;
}
.stars[data-stars="1"] .star:nth-child(1) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars[data-stars="2"] .star:nth-child(2) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars[data-stars="3"] .star:nth-child(3) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars[data-stars="4"] .star:nth-child(4) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars[data-stars="5"] .star:nth-child(5) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
```

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class RatingTest extends LightningElement {


    renderedCallback() {

            var box = this.template.querySelector('.stars');

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(box.getElementsByTagName('svg'), child => {
                child.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    let starEl = e.currentTarget;
                    console.log(starEl.parentNode.dataset.stars + ", " + starEl.dataset.rating);
                    this.clickedRating = starEl.dataset.rating;
                    console.log(this.clickedRating);
                    starEl.parentNode.setAttribute('data-stars', starEl.dataset.rating);
                  }.bind(this));
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put the main markup that is causing issues in the question? Your playground link could become invalid, and then this question would not be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: That's great. Also, to make it even better, you could edit the code to that which is the minimum that still causes the issue - ie just two two stars for example.

Comment: Oh... can you put the playground link back? It's pretty handy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Salesforce does not assign the shadowselector name consistently in the DOM.  It uses the the component name to add an attribute to all elements, but isnt consistent in the capitalisation of these across the elements.  It takes the component name and toLowers some parts of the name.  Chrome expects a case match to the css selectors for them to activate.

Two components: myRating and rating: same code, just the case different, and the first one doesn't work in Chrome, but the other does.

For others to see, go to the playground above and change app to myApp and then the CSS stops working.

Basically, you need to ensure your component name is all lowercase.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what were changes you had done for fix. It is not quite clear.

Comment: added some clarity

Comment: @Skynet5 are you saying the code that you pasted in your question will start working if we create a LWC with lowercase letters?

Comment: Certainly the CSS start to behave.  The reason it worked in the playground was because the default component is called app, all lower case.  I took your advice on the way I was attaching the onclick. That was left over from originally dynamically adding in element (lwc dom manual) however so likely it wouldnt have been left like that.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem seems to be in adding onclick on svg during rendered callback instead you can use div above your svg and simly put onlick on it[image]

```
<template>
        <div class="stars" data-stars="1">
          <div class="stardiv"  onclick={clicked} data-rating="1">
          <svg height="25" width="23" class="star" >
            <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>
          </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="stardiv"  onclick={clicked} data-rating="2">
          <svg height="25" width="23" class="star"  >
            <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>
          </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="stardiv"  onclick={clicked} data-rating="3" >
          <svg height="25" width="23" class="star" >
            <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>

          </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="stardiv"  onclick={clicked} data-rating="4" >
          <svg height="25" width="23" class="star" >
            <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>
          </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="stardiv"  onclick={clicked} data-rating="5">
          <svg height="25" width="23" class="star"  >
            <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></polygon>
          </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

and also change css a bit

```
.stars {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
  }
  .stars:hover .stardiv .star polygon {
    fill: #ffd055 !important;
  }
  .stars .stardiv .star polygon {
    fill: #d8d8d8;
  }
  .stars .stardiv:hover ~.stardiv .star polygon {
    fill: #d8d8d8 !important;
  }
  .stars[data-stars] .stardiv .star polygon {
    fill: #ffd055;
  }
  .stars[data-stars="1"] .stardiv:nth-child(1)~ .stardiv .star polygon {
    fill: #d8d8d8;
  }
  .stars[data-stars="2"] .stardiv:nth-child(2)~ .stardiv .star polygon {
    fill: #d8d8d8;
  }
  .stars[data-stars="3"] .stardiv:nth-child(3)~ .stardiv .star polygon {
    fill: #d8d8d8;
  }
  .stars[data-stars="4"] .stardiv:nth-child(4)~ .stardiv .star polygon{
    fill: #d8d8d8;
  }
  .stars[data-stars="5"] .stardiv:nth-child(5)~ .stardiv .star polygon {
    fill: #d8d8d8;
  }
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class RatingTest extends LightningElement {



    clicked(e){
        let starEl = e.currentTarget;
                    console.log(starEl.parentNode.dataset.stars + ", " + starEl.dataset.rating);
                    this.clickedRating = starEl.dataset.rating;
                    console.log(this.clickedRating);
                    starEl.parentNode.setAttribute('data-stars', starEl.dataset.rating);

    }
}
```

Comment: So I've just copied this in to my code and trying in local preview it makes no difference, I'm using Chrome BTW. I've noticed that in Safari it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Skynet5 strange it works for me on chrome

Comment: does the hovering work, so you can hover over the 3rd star and starts 1-3 light up?  I'm in chrome 80.  I've also noticed that if I enter developer mode in chrome after I've clicked on one the css takes effect.

Comment: yes hovering is working and the chrome is Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: are you on mac?  My version is Version 80.0.3987.149.

Comment: no i am using windows

Comment: Ok.  I've deployed the code to my Org and tried in a community and within the CRM on a Home page, on Windows in Chrome, and it also doesnt work. Did you copy all the fixed code up?

Comment: yes i copied all the things are you placing this LWC inside some other component or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106085/discussion-between-skynet5-and-user6670).